Ttk making own default styling
I try to create a widget with custom default styling, but it won't work.
I created ttk.style object for my own button class with ttk.Button as a parent:
defstyle = ttk.Style()
defstyle.configure('Main.TButton', background = 'red', foreground = 'blue')

class Button(ttk.Button):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

I want to make defstyle styling a default one, so the button would be styled this way without implicitly entering (...style='Main.TButton') option. I tried to do.
class Button(ttk.Button):
    def __init__(self, style,  *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.style = 'Main.TButton'

But it didn't work. What should I do?

To achieve the default styling for your custom button class using ttk, you need to set the default style for instances of your class. You can do this by overriding the init method of your custom button class. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

defstyle = ttk.Style()
defstyle.configure('Main.TButton', background='red', foreground='blue')

class Button(ttk.Button):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        style = kwargs.pop('style', 'Main.TButton')  # Remove 'style' from kwargs and use default 'Main.TButton' if not provided
        super().__init__(*args, style=style, **kwargs)

# Example usage:
root = tk.Tk()
button1 = Button(root, text='Button 1')
button1.pack()

button2 = Button(root, text='Button 2', style='Main.TButton')  # Explicitly specifying style
button2.pack()

root.mainloop()

In this code:

We override the init method of the Button class to accept the style argument. If style is not provided, it defaults to 'Main.TButton'.
We then call the init method of the parent class (ttk.Button) with the provided arguments, passing the style argument to it.
When creating instances of Button, you can either provide a style explicitly or rely on the default 'Main.TButton' style.

